How do I merge the contents of a Row's descendant Text and Button for TalkBack?
I have declared a Row which contains a Text and Button as follows:
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.semantics(mergeDescendants = true) { role = Role.Button }
) {
    Text("Date completed")
    Button(onClick = { }) {
        Text("November 2024")
    }
}

I was hoping that TalkBack would merge the contents of the Text and Button and read "Date completed November 2024, Button" when I focus on the Row. It doesn't. It reads "Date completed". Further, it still offers the Button as a focusable item. You can see an example of all this by running this sample app.
Can I give some further semantics to the Row, Text and Button so that (1) TalkBack reads "Date completed November 2024, Button" when I focus on the Row and (2) it does not offer the Button as an individually focusable item?

I have found three options for solving this problem. I will describe each solution below and then offer my opinion as to which I think is best.
Option 1
Give the Row a mergeDescendants value of true, clear the Button's semantics and then give the Button a contentDescription value of "November 2024", as follows:
val buttonText = "November 2024"

Row(
    modifier = Modifier.semantics(mergeDescendants = true) { role = Role.Button },
) {
    Text("Date completed")
    Button(
        onClick = { },
        modifier = Modifier.clearAndSetSemantics { contentDescription = buttonText }
    ) {
        Text(buttonText)
    }
}

TalkBack will read "Date completed November 2024, Button" when you focus on the Row and it won't offer the Button as an individually focusable item.
Option 2
Clear the semantics of the Row's descendants and give it a contentDescription of "Date completed November 2024", as follows:
val labelText = "Date completed"
val buttonText = "November 2024"

Row(
    modifier = Modifier.clearAndSetSemantics {
        contentDescription = "$labelText $buttonText"
        role = Role.Button
    },
) {
    Text(labelText)
    Button(onClick = { }) {
        Text(buttonText)
    }
}

TalkBack will read "Date completed November 2024" when you focus on the Row and it won't offer the Button as an individually focusable item.
Option 3
Clear the semantics of the Row's descendants, give it a contentDescription of "Date completed" and a stateDescription of "November 2024", as follows:
val labelText = "Date completed"
val buttonText = "November 2024"

Row(
    modifier = Modifier.clearAndSetSemantics {
        contentDescription = labelText
        stateDescription = buttonText
        role = Role.Button
    },
) {
    Text(labelText)
    Button(onClick = { }) {
        Text(buttonText)
    }
}

TalkBack will read "November 2024, Date completed, Button" when you focus on the Row and it won't offer the Button as an individually focusable item.
Which of the options is best?
In my opinion, Option 3 is best because it is more in line with how first-party Android views which contain a value (like Switch and Slider) behave: TalkBack reads the value of the view first, then its label or type. Further, whenever the view's value changes, TalkBack will read the new value.
